# How to set a style for a cell in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am using a datagrid in flex and need to render each cell with a different style.
What could be the best way to set a style to a perticular cell in datagrid/advanced datagrid (flex)?

I think one possible option can be extend the datagrid and override the drawRowBackgroungd function. Apart from this can i use some custom item renderer or some property similar to  label function of a series, there it used to return label here we need a style.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as soon as you ask what that "best way" to do something is, you're going to get a lot of subjectivity in your answers. What's best for someone new to Flex may not be what's best for a long time user. And everyone has their own preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Item renderers are your best option, you can use a canvas as your renderer and do whatever to it based on the data of that cell.

Comment: Thanks invertedSpear.
That means to use 'AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider' property with both 'columnspan' and 'rowspan' set to 1. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Renderers can be used in a lot of different ways. I would look up a tutorial online and work off of one of those. This is the Adobe quick start for what you're doing. See if it will help you: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_item_renderers/